# Skipping fields in a TinyTable application

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am using [Advanced JavaScript Table Sorter – TinyTable V3](http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/11/advanced-javascript-table-sorter/#comment-130116751).

After applying the sorter, the title fields will automatically be loaded into the dropdown list.

Does anyone know how to skip 1 or 2 fields so that the dropdown list is shorter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a quick look at the application and demo source I see that the selector is declared in the HTML with an id which is passed to the script in the option `colddid`.

After the applying the sorter, you can find the selector, traverse its children and delete any you do not want, something like this which will remove the 'All Columns' entry in the demo :

```
var selector = document.getElementById ('columns');
for (el = selector.lastChild; el; el = el.previousSibling) {
  // Traverse from last to first so that deletions do not disturb scan 
  if (el.innerHTML === 'All Columns') {
    selector.removeChild (el);
  }
}
```

Caveat : This is untested and I did not examine the sources closely to determine whther this manipulation would cause any problems, test appropraitely.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution.

Find this in the source.

```
var o=document.createElement('option'); o.value=i; o.innerHTML=T$$('h3',c)[0].innerHTML; d.appendChild(o)
```

And surround it with the condition:

```
if(c.className!='nosort'){
     var o=document.createElement('option'); o.value=i; o.innerHTML=T$$('h3',c)[0].innerHTML; d.appendChild(o)
}
```